# Fetching datasource on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got 2 sql DataSources with different select statements,

SQL datasource 1:

```
Select Emp_name, Emp_id from Employees where emp_Section = 1 and not Emp_id = 622501
```

And SQL datasource 2:

```
Select Emp_name, Emp_id from Employees where emp_Section = 2 and not Emp_id = 622501
```

so on page load i need to choose one of the sources in cs code to fill the listbox i tried

```
if(radiobuttonlist.selectedIndex == 1){

    listbox1.datasourceid  = sqldatasource2.load; //(this line i can't configure it correctly)
}
```

but it wasn't working.

and how can i bind this data source into a listbox to display the Emp_names as names and the Emp_ID as values on radio button change event handler

thanks in advance

Comment: can you add what have you tried

Comment: i added what i tried in my post please check it

Answer (score 1):

Change your code into this:

```
if(radiobuttonlist.selectedIndex == 1){
    listbox1.DataSourceID=sqldatasource2;
    listbox1.DataBind()  //Very Important
}
```

Regards!

Comment: thank you guys but i configured it by myself, its: listbox1.datasourceid = "sqldatasource2";